# Import python packages slower on Windows 10 in Sublime Text

Tags: python, windows-10, sublimetext3

Today I went from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and sadly I meet troubles with Sublime Text which is my main text editor. (my main specs are Intel Core i7, 8 GBRAM, 500 GB SSD on a laptop Dell XPS 14 L421x)

Running python in Spider is extremely fast (<1s). But in Sublime Text 3, just importing numpy, matplotlib and scipy takes up to 4 secondes. I really don't understand what is going on. I installed the last version of python 3.6.5 through Anaconda. I tested the same version on a Windows 7 computer and it does not have this issue (~1.5s for just the import).

Would you have any clue about what is going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it is just because my account was not Administrator of Windows. I don't know why dip down, but it solved the situation.